# GORM: How to query has many relation?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to find all `students` that belong to a `school` with a certain `name`.

```golang
type School struct {
    gorm.Model
    Students []Student
}

type Student struct {
    gorm.Model
    name string
    SchoolID uint 
}
```

I try this per the docs but it doesn't give me anything:

```
Database.Preload("Students", "name = ?", name).Find(&schools)
```

How can I achieve this with gorm?

Answer (score 1):

Preload method takes a function as second argument. Here is an example:

```
database.Model(&School{}).Preload("Students", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Where("studens.name = ?", name)
}).Find(&schools)
```